# Spring boot social media - facebook login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, facebook-login, spring-social

I'm trying to do facebook login using spring boot social. To do this I create url from facebook properties. I have url and when I get it from debug mode and put into browser it's working as I wish (so link is ok), but when I send redirect from spring controller nothing happen. In google chrome I can see that request was send and I can also see such errror in chrome console:

Failed to load [url]. Response for preflight is invalid (302 status).

My controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/connect/facebook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String send(Model model){
    String url = socialMediaService.createAuthorizationURL();
    return "redirect:" + url;
}
```

I know that it's some problem with redirecting to this link but I don't know how to do this in proper way.

EDIT:

It was all about CORS „Access-Control-Allow-Origin” attribute. It's enough to send this redirect trough javascript with dataType "jsonp", like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: data.url,
     type: "get",
     dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `"redirect:" + url` approach is intended for the use case where you might normally return a view. You can set that view's name to `"redirect:" + url` and then return it to issue a redirect instead of rendering your view normally. Since your controller operation is always redirecting, try returning a `RedirectView`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/connect/facebook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView send(Model model){
    String url = socialMediaService.createAuthorizationURL();
    return new RedirectView(url);
}
```

[Docs for RedirectView](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html)

Additionally, you will want to ensure that you use the correct one of `https` versus `http` and that your url is properly constructed. For example, `https://example.url/resource` may not be the same as `https://example.url/resource/`